# Create Shortcut in a android phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create a shortcut of my phonegap android app in Home screen using this plugin: https://github.com/jorgecis/ShortcutPlugin/tree/4c2c01cc2473f4d3af8bfb6809f5d647c0078d72

It says I need to write the following line:

```
 window.plugins.Shortcut.CreateShortcut("Text to show", successfunc, failfunc );
```

I have only `Index.html`, `Index.js` in my simple app. Where should I exactly add the line? Please help.

Comment: Please, add the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to wait for the [deviceready](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) event to make sure all Cordova device APIs have loaded.

In index.js, generated by `cordova create yourproject` there is already an `onDeviceReady` function. Put the line in there:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
  window.plugins.Shortcut.CreateShortcut("Text to show", successfunc, failfunc );
},
```